# Detect "super" word in java code using bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode, super

I am currently trying to count the number of super calls in java programs. In other words, I want to count the number of "super" in a given code. I have tried to use the invokespecial method from opcode, but the problem is that it counts additional cases where the word "super"
is not present.

I would greatly appreciate any help, this problem has been a huge pain!

**//edit 
I want to count the super.something cases not just super(); calls**

Comment: Can't just just parse the `.java` file?

Comment: Indeed it is an option but I would prefer a bytecode solution. If I use a parser I will also have to count the constructors which I want to avoid! Euxaristo pantos :-)

Answer (score 2):

`super` is strictly a Java language-level identifier; there is no direct equivalent in bytecode.

To find call sites like `super.method()`, you can look for `invokespecial` instructions which satisfy the following criteria:

1. The target method is not a constructor (i.e., not named `<init>`).
2. The target method's declaring type is not the current type (to filter out private methods).
3. The call site is not in a static method (see below).

Item #3 should handle false positives like those that would arise when the original code had an expression of the form `OuterClass.this.privateMethod()`.  In such cases, the compiler would emit a static accessor method that uses `invokespecial` to call `privateMethod()` on an `OuterClass` instance, and you don't want to include those.

If you want to include `super()` constructor calls, you will need to look for `invokespecial` instructions *within a constructor* that invoke another constructor; you can filter out `this()` calls by comparing the invoked constructor's declaring type to the current type.

You cannot reliably determine when `super.field` was *explicitly* used in the original source, as it is semantically equivalent to `this.field` in many cases (or even an unqualified access).  If you want to include any superclass field access, you can just compare the field's declaring type to the current type for any `getfield` and `putfield` instructions.  Otherwise, the best you can do is identify places where `super.field` **must** have been used, i.e., any field accesses where the target field is hidden by an identically named field in the current class.

If you want to detect accesses of the form `OuterClass.super.privateMethod()`, then you are in for some pain.  The compiler generates static accessor methods for these, and the conventions are an implementation detail of the compiler, so identifying them reliably is non-trivial.  You would also have to analyze the generated method to verify that the invoked method's declaring type doesn't match the instance parameter type (assuming the compiler actually typed the parameter as `OuterClass` and didn't just substitute its superclass directly).  And if the code was obfuscated, forget about it.

Comment: invokespecial is also used to invoke private methods

Comment: D'oh, you're right!  That throws a wrench into things.  Will update.

Comment: Updated to address additional edge cases for `invokespecial`, as well as `OuterClass.super` references.  Also, thinking about the latter pointed me to a bug in my decompiler!  \o/

Answer (score 0):

`super` is a keyword which means any parent class.

You don't need `super()` call counts as these will be one per constructor (except for `java.lang.Object`)

To be sure that `super` was used you have to look at method which use `this` as the first argument to a non-static method on a parent class.

You can do similar to count access to parent class fields.

Comment: thanks Peter, I updated the question. I want to count all the super.something calls not just super calls.

Comment: What is the difference? As I stated, you don't need the constructor calls.